# MySQL 5.7 Concatenate values of JSON string into one string

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-5.7, json-extract

I have a table where the `content` column consists of a JSON object, with an example value:

```
{"blocks":[{"score":"A"},{"score":"A"},{"score":"B"}]}
```

What I am trying to do is `SELECT` for a string representation of all the scores, so for this example I want:

```
AAB
```

I have been able to parse the JSON easily:

```
SELECT json_extract(content, '$.blocks[*].score') AS scores
```

Which results in:

```
["A", "A", "B"]
```

but for some reason I'm having an issue concatenating that JSON array into a single string (aside from casting it as a string and calling a few replace functions to remove the quotes and brackets). I've tried variations of `CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT` but have not found a solution.

What is the proper way to concatinate this JSON string into a single string?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in MySQL function that will join an array into a string.

Comment: If you normalized your schema instead of using JSON you could use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: In my observation, most questions about using JSON in MySQL could be answered: "this would be a lot easier if you didn't use JSON."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a catalog table such as `information_schema.tables` in order to generate rows to iterate by the length of the array, and then aggregate all members by using `GROUP_CONCAT()` such as

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                    JSON_UNQUOTE(
                       JSON_EXTRACT(content,
                                    CONCAT('$.blocks[', i - 1, '].score'))
                                   ) 
                       SEPARATOR '') AS scores
  FROM (SELECT JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(content, '$.blocks[*].score')) AS len,
               @i := @i + 1 AS i,
               content
          FROM tab
          JOIN information_schema.tables
          JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) AS i) AS t
 WHERE i <= len;

+--------+
| scores |
+--------+
|  AAB   |
+--------+
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e8ebe664090924eb9595bbf8ca9da475)</kbd>